# Android ellipsize:end dots count

Tags: android, textview

The ellipsize attribute with end value was perfect, under ICS version, but if I set this paramter and run the app there will be just 1 dot :(

2.3
http://kepfeltoltes.hu/120524/end_gb_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png

4.0
http://kepfeltoltes.hu/120524/2012-05-24_17.29.18_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png

Can I change the count of dots?

Comment: My experience is that I set just "singleLine=true" than it will working under ICS, JB...